# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The issue is that when I call **fnSelect** I get the error on chrome :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nTr' of undefined
```

Here is my code :

```
$('#ToolTables_table_id_0, #ToolTables_table_id_1').mousedown(function(){
                var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('table_id');
                var rowsToBeExported = $('#table_id tbody tr:visible');
                var visibileSelectedRows = $("#table_id tbody tr input[checked='checked']");
                if(visibileSelectedRows.size() > 0 ){
                    console.log(visibileSelectedRows);
                    console.log(rowsToBeExported);
                    oTT.fnSelect(visibileSelectedRows);
                }else{
                    $('input', rowsToBeExported).attr('checked','checked');
                }

                console.log(rowsToBeExported.size() + " row(s) will be exported.");
                oTT.fnSelect(rowsToBeExported);
            });
```

The error is fired by the line

```
oTT.fnSelect(visibileSelectedRows);
```

while the line

```
oTT.fnSelect(rowsToBeExported);
```

doesn't.

I've 11 columns and the last one is hidden by css code (display:none)

Any explanation please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are passing the checkbox element to `fnSelect` in `oTT.fnSelect(visibileSelectedRows)`.

`$("#table_id tbody tr input[checked='checked']")` will give you the checkbox element. You need to find its parent `tr` and pass it to `fnSelect`. Try this.

```
$('#ToolTables_table_id_0, #ToolTables_table_id_1').mousedown(function(){
                var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('table_id');
                var rowsToBeExported = $('#table_id tbody tr:visible');
                var visibileSelectedRows = $("#table_id tbody tr input[checked='checked']");
                if(visibileSelectedRows.size() > 0 ){
                    console.log(visibileSelectedRows);
                    console.log(rowsToBeExported);
                    oTT.fnSelect(visibileSelectedRows.closest('tr'));
                }else{
                    $('input', rowsToBeExported).attr('checked','checked');
                }

                console.log(rowsToBeExported.size() + " row(s) will be exported.");
                oTT.fnSelect(rowsToBeExported);
            });
```

Comment: Thank you !! I'm ok with you !